# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar una columna haciendo JOIN en la misma tabla?

Tags: mysql

Necesito actualizar la columna `nombre` de algunas filas de mi tabla usando el valor de otras filas relativas en esa misma tabla.

Para que se entienda mejor, he aquí una imagen de los resultados que arroja esta consulta:

```
SELECT id_celebracion, id_tipo, dia, semana, id_tiempo, nombre 
FROM liturgia 
WHERE 
semana=11 AND id_tiempo=7 
ORDER BY id_tipo,dia;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi `UPDATE` yo quisiera asignar el valor de la columna `nombre` respectivo según el día y la semana. O sea:

- Asignar el valor de `nombre` del id `588` también al id `212`
- Asignar el valor de `nombre` del id `589` también al id `213`
- Etc...

El criterio es que ellos coinciden en `dia`, en `semana` y en `id_tiempo`  y se diferencian únicamente en que en uno el `id_tipo` es `49` y en otro es `50`.

Normalmente, la consulta que yo haría sería esta:

```
UPDATE liturgia AS n
INNER JOIN liturgia AS o ON
  (n.dia=o.dia AND n.semana=o.semana AND n.id_tiempo=o.id_tiempo)
SET
  n.nombre = o.nombre
WHERE o.semana=11 and o.id_tiempo=7
```

Pero al aislar un `SELECT` para probar y no causar una catástrofe en la BD:

```
SELECT * from  liturgia AS n
INNER JOIN liturgia AS o ON
  (n.dia=o.dia AND n.semana=o.semana AND n.id_tiempo=o.id_tiempo)
WHERE o.semana=11 and o.id_tiempo=7;
```

Obtengo un resultado de **33 filas**, por lo que algo no anda bien en mi consulta.

¿Mediante qué consulta podría entonces lograr la actualización requerida?

Comment: Hola, creo que lo tengo, solo una pregunta, ¿existe un elemento con nombre para los días domingo (1) ?

Comment: @the-breaker Sí. Pero como son menos, los he dejado aislados, pensando que podría resolverlo luego, con la misma lógica implementada para los días de semana. Realmente los días de semana tienen dos ciclos (par e impar) indentificados por el valor `49` y `50` respectivamente. Para los domingos en cambio hay tres ciclos (A, B, y C). La idea es, para no tener que escribirlo todo de nuevo, volcar lo de los Impares en los Pares y luego a mano cambiar la palabra `Impar` por la palabra `Par`

Answer (score 1):

Digamos que tienes un modelo base de nombres por semana y día que quieres aplicar en aquellos casos dónde no tienes estos nombres. Este modelo base que abarca una hasta una semana entera, sería algo así:

```
SELECT dia, semana, nombre 
       FROM liturgia 
       WHERE semana=11 
             AND id_tiempo=7 
             AND id_tipo=49;
```

Ahora puedes aplicarlo al resto de las filas que no tienen `nombre`, a la manera de una consulta, simplemente para verificar el funcionamiento:

```
SELECT L.*, M.nombre
       FROM liturgia L
       INNER JOIN (SELECT dia, semana, nombre 
                          FROM liturgia 
                          WHERE semana=11 
                          AND id_tiempo=7 
                          AND nombre is not null
                  ) M
                  ON L.dia = M.dia
                  AND L.semana = M.semana
       WHERE L.nombre is null
```

Y para actualizar, podrías hacer:

```
UPDATE liturgia L
       INNER JOIN (SELECT dia, semana, nombre 
                          FROM liturgia 
                          WHERE semana=11 
                          AND id_tiempo=7 
                          AND nombre is not null
                  ) M
                  ON L.dia = M.dia
                  AND L.semana = M.semana
       SET L.nombre = M.nombre
       WHERE L.nombre is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a cruzar la tabla consigo misma, por un lado los id_tipo que sí tienen el campo nombre rellenado (49) y en otro el resto (distinto de 49).

Algo así:

```
update liturgia l1
inner join liturgia l2 on l1.dia = l2.dia and l1.semana = l2.semana and l1.id_tiempo = l2.id_tiempo set l2.nombre = l1.nombre
where l1.id_tipo = 49 and l2.id_tipo <> 49;
```

(edito) no vi que se trataba de mysql, cambio el código